# How to transfer files from putty (Linux) directory to Windows folder?

Tags: putty

I just want to ask on how am I going to transfer my files in putty (Linux terminal) directory to my Windows `C:\xampp\mysql` folder. Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PuTTY can't do this.  You will need an SFTP client, either one from the PuTTY suite, or Filezilla or similar, and will need to SFTP to your server (with your SSH credentials, to your SSH port), and download the data from your Linux system to your Windows computer.  (This assumes the Linux system is not on your computer in a dual boot configuration and is on a remote server.)